# Better alternative to autonumber primary keys

Tags: ms-access, database-design, primary-key

I am looking for a better primary key than the autonumber data type, namely for the reason that it's limited to a long integer, when I really just need the field to reflect a number or text string that will never ever repeat, no matter HOW many records are added or deleted from the table.  The problem is I am not sure how to implement something like turning the current date and time into a hexadecimal string and using that as a unique field I can use as a primary key.

Am I just being too paranoid about running out of space?

-- EDITED 03-16-2010 @ 1237 hours --

I had a person who, at the time, I thought was a wonderful reference for Access related questions tell me that Replication IDs are just a counter for the number of times an item was replicated...  hence I never explored it further.  After the number of replies, I have up-modded, and accepted an answer.  I guess I was just having a stupid newbie Accesss developer moment.  Seriously though, thank you again for everyone who replied!

Comment: An autonumber field is a long, 4 bytes, and can have 2,147,483,647 records.  Then there's the negative numbers which would another  -2,147,483,648 records If you are concerned about running out of space I would recommend storiung your data in a data system other than Access aka Jet format.

Comment: It's not clear if you're programming your application in Access or not. If so, then you've just added problems to your development process, as outlined in the Michael Kaplan article cited by Tony Toews in comments downthread. You may be happy with those, but I mostly think that people who think they need GUIDs in an Access app without an outside dependency forcing the issue are mostly fooling themselves and introducing unnecessary development problems. But note that I said "mostly" and not "always".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUID.
They are pretty unique

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier

You did not mention your programming language.
C# would be something like

```
String myKey = Guid.NewGuid().toString();
```

Comment: Read the following article before considering GUIDs.  Subject: INFO: Replication and GUIDs, the Good, the Bad, and the Ugly 
http://www.trigeminal.com/usenet/usenet011.asp?1033

Comment: if you set the database to have a Text value and put your GUID in manually would that solve all the problems listed on your link. And for point 4. No one want to be a number just as much as the don't want to be a random bunch of letters. If i were making a system it would be able to find a record with out the use of a Primary Key

Comment: Changing to text type is going to alter the indexing, and it's probably less efficient (the letters in a GUID are not text, but Hex numbers). But I don't know for sure -- I've never seen a reason to use a GUID as a PK (though all my replicated databases use them for replication functions, something I leave entirely to the database engine).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you'll run out of space? Perhaps you do not realize how big a 64-bit integer is, exactly. It allows for around 10 billion billion records. If you created 100 records per second, it would take over [five billion years](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E64+%2F+%28100+%2F+%281+second%29%29) to run out of integers.

Comment: An Access `Long` type is only 32 bits.

Comment: OOH!!!! Only 32 bits! If Jet/ACE is appropriate as data store for the application, then the Jet/ACE long integer is going to be sufficient. If the first condition is not met, then the issue is not with the choice of Autonumber as PK.

Comment: Technically, Microsoft Access only uses 4 bytes to store a long integer, hence the original question - but I've gotten a response that works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you limited to a long integer? When you specify an AutoNumber field, you can tell it to use a `Replication ID` instead of `Long Integer` and it will be a unique 128-bit value called a GUID.

Although you can use the current date and time as a primary key, here's why not to:

*The current date and time are not as unique as you might think*. If you make records very rapidly, you could end up with two being inserted between clock ticks, causing both to end up with the same time. Or your computer's clock could just get reset backwards. Or DST could end and if you're storing local times, you'll end up with duplicate times.

Comment: I would not advise using DateTime stamp as a primary key.

Comment: Indeed, Kieran, the bulk of my post was explaining why it's not a good idea.

Comment: +1 after edit. Replication ID is database specific and remove the need for putting it in code. Better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Per John's answer, you're unlikely to run out of long integers.  But if you'd prefer a unique string, the easiest solution is a UUID.  It doesn't take inputs, but the odds of ever generating two identical UUIDs are negligible.

For example, in Python:

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4()
```

There are UUID functions available in most all languages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid

Comment: In what circumstance in which Jet/ACE is an appropriate data store would you ever run out of long integers?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to use an Autonumber with option "Random" instead of "Increment". I read somewhere that since the numbers are not contiguous, it has the added bonus of improving concurrency when adding new records from several clients simultaneously.

Comment: Actually, when adding records, it doesn't improve concurrency, as new records (and the corresponding index values) are going to be stored in new data pages. But for editing existing data in a compacted file, it would, theoretically, spread the data evenly over all the data pages, which could improve concurrency. But it's only after a compact that you'd get perfect results from that, and it only applies to editing existing records, not record additions.

Comment: @David, Thanks for the explanation. Now I think I remember I saw that information in one of your posts on SO. Interesting...and remembered ;-)